# Who's the girl on the cover of chapter 67?

Tags: dragon-ball

Who's the girl on the cover of the *Dragon Ball* manga, chapter 67? Is it just random art? It is not featured in the chapter!

[image: Chapter 67 manga cover]

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing who the dinosaur is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is not known to have any name, nor has she appeared elsewhere besides the cover.

From [Dragon Ball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Go_West,_Young_Goku): "*The cover of this chapter shows Goku and a young cavewoman riding a dinosaur with a prehistoric-like background.*"

Answer (score 2):

When I saw that girl in that cover, she actually seemed to me like the girl from the next chapter (68) whom Goku has some interaction:
[image]